# Value of type 'Any' has no member 'int'. Unable to fetch count of rows from PostgresClientKit

Tags: swift, apache-age

I am trying to fetch the count of rows from the PostgreSQL database using PostgresClientKit but I am getting the following error
Value of type 'Any' has no member 'int'.

This is the code

```
let rows = fetchSQL(statement: "SELECT count(*) FROM ag_graph WHERE name='" + graphName + "'", connection: connection);
        
        let row_counts = rows[0] as! [Any];
        let count = try row_counts[0].int();
        if count < 1{
            // My Code
        }
```

I have tried printing the rows. It is

> [[1]]

The definition of fetchSQL function is as follow

```
func fetchSQL(statement:String, connection:Connection)-> [Any]{
    var rows:[Any] = [];
    do{
        let statement = try connection.prepareStatement(text: statement)
        defer { statement.close() }
        
        let cursor = try statement.execute()
        defer { cursor.close() }

        for row in cursor {
            rows.append(try row.get().columns);
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Have your tried this: `let count = rows.count` then `print("\(count)")`. 
 Note there is no need for the `;` in Swift

Comment: Well you need to adjust your cast to what you actually get back, what about debugging or adding some print statements to  fetchSQL to see what the content is of a row (I would guess it's simply an Int since you are returning the result of `count(*)` but that is just my guess). Also what type has a function int()`? Looks like you are actually expecting a specific type here.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine That is always 1 since the sql query is returning one row.

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved. PostgreSQLClientKit returns a specific type of PostgresValue that can be converted to int using int() funciton

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like you are trying to call the int() method on an instance of Any which doesn't have that method. Try casting the value to the appropriate type first.

```
let row_counts = rows[0] as! [Any]
let count = row_counts[0] as! Int // cast to Int instead of using int()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way . It will probably help.

```
 let rows = fetchSQL(statement: "SELECT count(*) FROM ag_graph WHERE name='" + graphName + "'", connection: connection);
            print(rows)
            let row_counts = rows[0] as! [PostgresValue];
            let count = try row_counts[0].int();
            if count < 1{
                // your code
            }
```